# Crear un servicio windows con java

Tags: java, windows, servicio

Buen dia, he estado investigando mucho pero no logro encontrar como crear un servicio windows con java, mi aplicacion es muy sencilla, solo tiene manejo de archivos. he intentado creado el `jar` en `exe` y utilizando el comando:

> `sc.exe createTestJavaServicebinPath "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\testservicio\ServicioJavaTest.exe"`

y crea el servicio correctamente pero no lo inica debido a que queda con el error 1053

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Windows suele tener líos para saber si esos exe realmente se iniciaron sin errores, etc. Mi recomendación es usar [WinSW](https://github.com/winsw/winsw) para crear el servicio ejecutando el JAR.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, eternamente agradecido, es justo lo que necesitaba.